# Undefined Offset [PHP / JQUERY]

Tags: php, jquery

So I was trying to add row via append of JQuery. It reads how many rows but it only reads [0]. When I try to add row, only the first row were able to read.

HTML CODE:

```
        <table class="POTable">
            <tr><form name="AddPO" id="AddPO">
                <td colspan="3" align="center">PURCHASE ORDER INFORMATION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 10%">PO NUMBER:</td>
              <td style="width: 40%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="PO Number" id="PONum1" name="PONum" /></td>
              <td style="width: 50%" align="center">Date:<input class="PODate" disabled="disabled" input type="date" id="DateCreated1" name="DateCreated" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 10%">COMPANY:</td>
              <td style="width: 40%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="PO Number" id="POCompany1" name="POCompany" /></td>
              <td style="width: 50%" ><input  class="POtxtbx" type="text" id="Sample1" name="ctr"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 10%">CONTACT PERSON:</td>
              <td style="width: 40%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="PO Number" id="POName1" name="POName" /></td>
              <td style="width: 50%" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><div style="height: 5px; background-color: black; width: 100%; border-radius: 35px"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="POItemTable" id="ItemField">
            <tr>
          <td style="width: 20%" align="left">
            QUANTITY:
          </td>
          <td>
            UNITS:
          </td>
          <td>
            ITEM CODE:
          </td>
          <td>
            ITEM NAME:<br>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="POtxtbx" type="Number" placeholder="QUANTITY" id="Quantity1" name="Quant[0]"/></td>
          <td><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="UNIT" id="Unit1" name="Unit[0]"/></td>
          <td><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="ITEM CODE" id="ItemCode1" name="ItemCode[0]"/></td>
          <td><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="ITEM NAME" id="ItemName1" name="ItemName[0]"/></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Item"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="POTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%"><input type="button" class="POSaveButton" value="Save"></td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table></form>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 1;
    $("#Sample1").val(a);

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            a++;
            var markup = "<tr id='row"+a+"'><td><input class='POtxtbx' type='Number' placeholder='QUANTITY' id='Quantity1' name='Quant['"+a+"']/></td><td><input class='POtxtbx' type='text' placeholder='UNIT' id='Unit1' name='Unit['"+a+"']' /></td><td><input class='POtxtbx' type='text' placeholder='ITEM CODE' id='ItemCode1' name='ItemCode['"+a+"']'/></td><td><input class='POtxtbx' type='text' placeholder='ITEM NAME' id='ItemName1' name='ItemName['"+a+"']'/></td><td align='right'><input id='"+a+"' type='button' class='delete-row' value='&times'></td>";
            $("#ItemField").append(markup);
            $("#Sample1").val(a);
        });

       $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function(){
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            a--;
            $("#Sample1").val(a);
        });

       //Save Button
       $(".POSaveButton").click(function(){
            var POCOmp = $('#POCompany1').val();
            var PONumb = $('#PONum1').val();
            var DateCreat = $('#DateCreated1').val();
            var PONam =$('#POName1').val();
            var ItemQuant = $('#Quantity1').val();
            var ItemUnit = $('#Unit1').val();
            var ItemCod = $('#ItemCode1').val();
            var ItemNam = $('#ItemName1').val();
            var cntr = $('#Sample1').val();

            if(POCOmp == "")
              {
                   alert("Company field is required");
              }
             else if(PONam == "")
              {
                    alert("Name field is required");
              }
             else if(PONumb == "")
              {
                    alert("PO Number field is required");
              }
              else{
                $.ajax({
                    url:"insert.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:$('#AddPO').serializeArray(),
                    success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    }
                });

              }

       });
    });
</script>
```

PHP CODE (insert.php)

```
<?php
//insert.php

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_is");

        $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["POCompany"]);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["POName"]);
        $Date = date("Y-m-d");
        $PONumm = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["PONum"]);

        $counter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ctr"]);

        $sample = $_POST["ItemCode"];
        $sample1 = $_POST["ItemName"];
        $sample2 = $_POST["Unit"];
        $sample3 = $_POST["Quant"];


        for ($a = 0; $a < $counter; $a++) { 
            # code...


            $sample = "";
            $sample1 = "";
            $sample2 = "";
            $sample3 = "";

            $sample = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ItemCode"][$a]);
            $sample1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ItemName"][$a]);
            $sample2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Unit"][$a]);
            $sample3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Quant"][$a]);


                mysqli_query($con,$sql); */

            if ($sample != "" && $sample1 != "" && $sample2 != "" && $sample3 != ""){

                echo $sample . " " . $sample1 . " " . $sample2 . " " . $sample3;

            }

            else{

                echo "EMPTY " . $a;


            }

        }

?>
```

Thanks in advance. This error is a nightmare for me. Its been a week since I code this and still not resolved. I hope you'd help me.

--Roseheim

Comment: have you just tried tidying your code - the form element is not correctly aligned with it close element (for a start) - and name='Quant['"+a+"']/> - it's missing data - garbage in garbade out

Comment: Hi Sir David, thank you for taking your time to help. As of now, I've already resolved the error. And it's working properly. -- Roseheim

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your code.
First, never use `id` for multiple same html elements instead of ids use `class` bcoz id is unique for each element.
Second, use `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()` because `serializeArray()` send form data as name value pair and your php code not work with this.

Try below code may be it can help you.

```js
var a = 1;
$("#Sample1").val(a);

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".add-row").click(function() {
    var markup = "<tr id='row"+a+"'><td><input class='POtxtbx Quantity1' type='Number' placeholder='QUANTITY' name='Quant["+a+"]' /></td><td><input class='POtxtbx Unit1' type='text' placeholder='UNIT' name='Unit["+a+"]' /></td><td><input class='POtxtbx ItemCode1' type='text' placeholder='ITEM CODE' name='ItemCode["+a+"]'/></td><td><input class='POtxtbx ItemName1' type='text' placeholder='ITEM NAME'  name='ItemName["+a+"]'/></td><td align='right'><input id='"+a+"' type='button' class='delete-row' value='&times'></td></tr>";
    $("#ItemField").append(markup);
    a++;
    $("#Sample1").val(a);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    a--;
    $("#Sample1").val(a);
  });

  //Save Button
  $(".POSaveButton").click(function() {
    var POCOmp = $('#POCompany1').val();
    var PONumb = $('#PONum1').val();
    var PONam = $('#POName1').val();
    console.log($('#AddPO').serialize());
    if (POCOmp == "") {
      alert("Company field is required");
    } else if (PONam == "") {
      alert("Name field is required");
    } else if (PONumb == "") {
      alert("PO Number field is required");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#AddPO').serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="AddPO" id="AddPO">
  <table class="POTable">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">PURCHASE ORDER INFORMATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%">PO NUMBER:</td>
      <td style="width: 40%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="PO Number" id="PONum1" name="PONum" /></td>
      <td style="width: 50%" align="center">Date:<input class="PODate" disabled="disabled" input type="date" id="DateCreated1" name="DateCreated" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%">COMPANY:</td>
      <td style="width: 40%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="PO Number" id="POCompany1" name="POCompany" /></td>
      <td style="width: 50%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" id="Sample1" name="ctr" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%">CONTACT PERSON:</td>
      <td style="width: 40%"><input class="POtxtbx" type="text" placeholder="PO Number" id="POName1" name="POName" /></td>
      <td style="width: 50%" align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <div style="height: 5px; background-color: black; width: 100%; border-radius: 35px"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="POItemTable" id="ItemField">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20%" align="left">
        QUANTITY:
      </td>
      <td>
        UNITS:
      </td>
      <td>
        ITEM CODE:
      </td>
      <td>
        ITEM NAME:<br>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="POtxtbx Quantity1" type="Number" placeholder="QUANTITY" name="Quant[0]" /></td>
      <td><input class="POtxtbx Unit1" type="text" placeholder="UNIT" name="Unit[0]" /></td>
      <td><input class="POtxtbx ItemCode1" type="text" placeholder="ITEM CODE" name="ItemCode[0]" /></td>
      <td><input class="POtxtbx ItemName1" type="text" placeholder="ITEM NAME" name="ItemName[0]" /></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Item"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="POTable">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20%"><input type="button" class="POSaveButton" value="Save"></td>
      <td style="width: 20%">
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

PHP Code-

```
<?php
//insert.php

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_is");

        $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["POCompany"]);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["POName"]);
        $Date = date("Y-m-d");
        $PONumm = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["PONum"]);

        $counter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ctr"]);


        for ($a = 0; $a < $counter; $a++) { 
            # code...

            $sample = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ItemCode[".$a."]"]);
            $sample1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ItemName[".$a."]"]);
            $sample2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Unit[".$a."]"]);
            $sample3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Quant[".$a."]"]);


                mysqli_query($con,$sql); */

            if ($sample != "" && $sample1 != "" && $sample2 != "" && $sample3 != ""){

                echo $sample . " " . $sample1 . " " . $sample2 . " " . $sample3;

            }

            else{

                echo "EMPTY " . $a;


            }

        }

?>
```

Comment: Hi Sir Shubham, thank you for taking your time to help. As of now, I've already resolved the error. And it's working properly.

Comment: Happy to help you. :)